# How to configure FxCop rule and run it using FxCop Runner in VS2010 Profesional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fxcop

**I've this environment:**
I'm using "FxCop 10" and "Visual Studio 2010 Profesional". I connected the FxCop to Visual Studio 2010 Profesional using "FxCop Runner".

**This is my purpose:**
I want to disable some rule for my project, and integrated it with others projects (in the same solution). I also want to save that configuration in source control, so my team member can use it easily.

**And this is my experience:**
As StyleCop can generate the "Settings.StyleCop" file and can be referred by other projects.

**My question is:**
can I do the similar way for FxCop?

Regards,

Aditya

Answer (score 3):

FxCop supports two mechanisms for this.  The first is a `.fxcop` project file, which can be created via the FxCop UI application.  This is probably your simplest option.

The second approach is a `.ruleset` file, for which the UI editor is Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate for VS 2010 (or Professional if you have VS 2013 as well).  If you don't have one of these editions, you could edit a `.ruleset` file manually since it's just XML, but it sounds like there's no reason not to use a `.fxcop` file in your case.

Comment: Hi Nicole. 
Yup, I've tried create .fxcop project. But, my problem is.. how to integrate the .fxcop project with the VS 2010 Prof? I need to integrate that rules with my VS, so when I right click my project and hit "FxCop Runner" no warning appears for the rules which i already exclude in my .fxcop project.

Comment: FxCop Runner appears to allow setting `fxcopcmd.exe` command line options via its "Other command line arguments" setting (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/706b0d9f-9726-474e-b687-2bb9704c9784).  You can use the `/project` option to specify the `.fxcop` project file to use (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429449(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Tank you Nicole. I'll try you suggestion. It seem you are the one who understand fxcop here. salute..